# How well do microcontrollers deal with unstable power supplies?

Tags: microcontroller, noise

Assuming the VCC voltage never goes below the minimum of the specific chip (1.8v for the ATmega48PV) or above the maximum, how well do microcontrollers deal with noise? Are they guaranteed not to malfunction? Does anything happen, apart from I guess ADC readings might get a bit funny and inputs and outputs fluctuate?

Comment: Read the datasheet, every µC is different.

Comment: @Plas: I've never seen a spec for this in any microcontroller datasheet.

Comment: @OlinLathrop me neither

Comment: @OlinLathrop: A few rare ones (I have seen in the aviation industry) do specify some limited guarantees. If they don't then there is no guarantee for them to not malfunction. "Undefined behaviour" the programmer would say.

Comment: ATMegas like to start running reliable on body touch leakage current...

Answer (score 3):

In theory they should be fine since you aren't violating any specs.  However, there is probably a upper frequency limit on supply voltage variations that will cause trouble.  You can only guess what that might be since datasheets don't tell you.

Do what you can to limit the frequency of the fluctuations.  You always need a good high frequency bypass cap on every power lead to the nearest ground lead.  If your supply voltage might otherwise fluctuate at high frequency, add additional capacitance.  For example, a 1 µF ceramic for every power lead, and then maybe 10 µF or more near the chip where all the power leads are tied together.

Consider adding a ferrite chip inductor in series with the supply before all the capacitors mentioned above.  This should be followed by 10s of µF capacitance, plus the individual bypass caps.  The inductance and capacitance form a second order low pass filter that attenuate high frequencies significantly.

The drawback is that there will be some voltage drop across the ferrite chip inductor.  These are designed for this kind of use, so have only a few 100 mΩ at most, but that can still be a problem in some cases.  It helps to keep the heavy current draw off the microcontroller power feed.  If the micro needs to drive LEDs, for example, have the micro control transistors, which then control the LED current coming from some other supply or from before the chip inductor.

Ultimately, you'll have to talk to the manufacturer to get a real answer, if you're ever going to get one at all.  The best strategy is to avoid being in this situation in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I just went looking for it in the Atmega328 datasheet and couldn't see it. For analogue parts this is specified as PSRR (power supply rejection ratio).

What that datasheet does specify is the affect of VCC on pin thresholds and internal oscillator behaviour. That suggests that if your power supply is sufficiently noisy you will may glitches on input pins that may manifest as errors in e.g. fast SPI. You may also disrupt the internal oscillator.

Answer (score 0):

They are not guaranteed not to malfunction. They probably will.

However, the bypass capacitors will place some kind of limit on the maximum dv/dt on the power supply (assuming the current drawn from the power supply is known) so you can at least quantify the problem.

It's probably a reasonable guess that, at least, the digital parts won't care much if the rate of change is less than a certain amount- say 10,000 clock cycles to slew the worst-case range from 1.8V to 5.5V peak-to-peak (of course we're assuming the clock is at or below the **maximum 4MHz for 1.8V operation**) so that would be about +/-1500V/second or a ripple frequency of about 500Hz for 1.3V RMS (full range).